# Agenda span of "last 7 days"

Tags: org-mode

I write my weekly report on Wednesdays. As such I need to see what I've done starting last Wednesday until now. (usually a Wednesday).

I would like to create an Agenda view for this, so I can quickly flick between the weeks, but I cannot find a way of specifying '-7' days.

I tried customizing `org-agenad-custom-commands` and setting the days to '-7' but that only shows the current day.

At present I generate a report for this:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tstart "<-6d>" :tend "<now>" :scope agenda-with-archives :narrow 70 :formatter my-org-clocktable-notodo :maxlevel 3 :fileskip0
```

But I can't find a way to transpose this to an Agenda custom view. Is this possible?

**[Edit solution]**
As per lawlist's advise in the comment I got it to work.

1) I customized `org-agenad-custom-commands`, added an agenda view that shows "Number of days in agenda" = 8. I assigned "W" to this agenda view.

```
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands
   ....
     ("W" "Last 8 days." agenda ""
      ((org-agenda-span 8)
  ...
```

2) I then defined a function that temporarily defines the variable:

```
(defun my/agenda-last-week () 
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-start-day "-7d"))
       (org-agenda nil "W"))
)
```

I then assign a hotkey to that function.

Now I can view my last week Wednesday to Wednesday, (inc time-report).  I am happy.

Comment: The second argument to `org-agenda-list` is `start-day`, and the third argument is `span`.  `M-x describe-function RET org-agenda-list RET`.  See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html  E.g., *You can also set the start date using a date shift: `(setq org-agenda-start-day "+10d")` will start the agenda ten days from today in the future.*  Presumably you can go the opposite direction with a negative argument.  In a custom command situation, the `setq` is omitted because it takes on a let-bound value.

Comment: See also, `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-start-day RET`  Here is a link to a thread that deals with what appears to be the same issue, entitled **A weekly review in org-mode**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422781/a-weekly-review-in-org-mode

Comment: @lawlist Negative values for `org-agenda-start-day` do work exactly the way you suspect.  I think your comment is really an answer.

Comment: @lawlist, that actually solves it :-). If you post an answer, I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `org-agenda-start-day` can be used to achieve the behavior desired by the original poster.  The doc-string provides as follows:

```
Start day for the agenda view.
Custom commands can set this variable in the options section.
This is usually a string like "2007-11-01", "+2d" or any other
input allowed when reading a date through the Org calendar.
See the docstring of `org-read-date' for details.
```

The manual -- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html -- contains the following example:  *You can also set the start date using a date shift: `(setq org-agenda-start-day "+10d")` will start the agenda ten days from today in the future.*